# azurerm_mssql_server creation fails beacuse of time_out

Tags: azure, terraform, workflow, pipeline

I have a pipeline [in this repository](https://github.com/salman-/basic-price-predictor) and I use it to create infrastructure in the Azure cloud. When I run the commands of pipeline **locally** it works *well*, however when I run it using the pipeline it fails because of timeout error:

```
Error: waiting for creation/update of Server: (Name "sqlserverforforex" / Resource Group "RG-Terraform-on-Azure"): Future#WaitForCompletion: context has been cancelled: StatusCode=200 -- Original Error: context deadline exceeded
│ 
│   with module.database.azurerm_mssql_server.sql_server_for_price_prediction,
│   on modules/database/mssql_database.tf line 2, in resource "azurerm_mssql_server" "sql_server_for_price_prediction":
│    2: resource "azurerm_mssql_server" "sql_server_for_price_prediction" {
```

[Here you can find the full log of the build.](https://github.com/salman-/basic-price-predictor/actions/runs/3176025908/jobs/5174820925)

The provision of infrastructure **finishes successfully locally after 2:30 minutes**, therefore i gave a `timeout` block to the `azurerm_mssql_server` for `10 minutes` and this must be enough time for it. However, even without timeout it takes 60 minutes and it still fails.

```
resource "azurerm_mssql_server" "sql_server_for_price_prediction" {
  name                         = "sqlserverforforex"
  resource_group_name          = var.resource_group_name
  location                     = var.resource_group_location
  version                      = "12.0"
  administrator_login          = "4dm1n157r470r"
  administrator_login_password = "4-v3ry-53cr37-p455w0rd"

  timeouts {
    create = "10m"
    delete = "20m"
  }
}
```

So, i guess, something is wrong in my pipeline but i don't know what is the problem ?

Why the pipeline cannot create infrastructure meanwhile the local run is successful?

The pipeline by itself just ran the below commands

```
terraform init
terraform fmt -check
terraform plan -input=false
terraform get
terraform import azurerm_resource_group.main_resource_group "/subscriptions/${{env.ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID}}/resourceGroups/RG-Terraform-on-Azure"
terraform apply -auto-approve -parallelism=5
```

Comment: Any reason for limiting the parallelism to 5?

Comment: No, the default timeout is 60 minutes and it is too much to see the result. Also, i run it locally and it took only 2:30 minutes, so 10 minutes is really more than what it needs.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue is there any steps that I can take to resolve it I have a similar case and creation is always getting timed out.

Comment: Im seeing the same problem here in creating an Azure SQL Server via a pipeline, have logged a bug on the MS GitHub at all? If not I will do so and reference this question as well.

Comment: Any progress on that issue?